# Pasting array of JSON into typescript array

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, ionic2

I have an array of JSON and want to paste it into an array variable in typescript.

the JSON I receive from http://www.example.com/select.php:

```
{ 
     "User":[ 
      {"Name":"Luca M","ID":"1"},
      {"Name":"Tim S","ID":"2"},
      {"Name":"Lucas W","ID":"3"} 
     ] 
    }
```

I would like to get an array like that:

```
  this.items = [
          'Luca M',
          'Tim S',
          'Lucas W'
        ];
```

EDIT:

current code is

```
 this.http.post('http://www.example.com/select.php', creds, {
          headers: headers
      })
          .map(res => res.json().User) 

          .subscribe(
          data => this.data = data.User.map(user => user.Name), 
          err => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Completed')
          );


      this.items = this.data;
```

error:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

how can I realize this?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this very specific json:

```
const json = {
    "User": [
        { "Name": "Luca M", "ID": "1" },
        { "Name": "Tim S", "ID": "2" },
        { "Name": "Lucas W", "ID": "3" } 
    ] 
}

const items = json.User.map(user => user.Name);
console.log(items); // ["Luca M", "Tim S", "Lucas W"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22User%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22Name%22%3A%20%22Luca%20M%22%2C%20%22ID%22%3A%20%221%22%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22Name%22%3A%22Tim%20S%22%2C%22ID%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%22Name%22%3A%22Lucas%20W%22%2C%22ID%22%3A%223%22%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20items%20%3D%20json.User.map(user%20%3D%3E%20user.Name)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(items)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22Luca%20M%22%2C%20%22Tim%20S%22%2C%20%22Lucas%20W%22%5D))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I forgot to mention, that I receive my JSON from an API. Could you help me once more according to my Edit?

Comment: I tried 
const json = JSON.stringify(this.data);
this.items = this.data.map(user => user.Name); 
but this did not work as I expected

Comment: You don't need to `stringify` your data, if you do that you end up with a string and not an object...

Comment: Alright, makes sense, but it does not work either
 this.items = this.data.map(User => User.Name); 
--Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: You're probably doing an asynchronous operation. You need to wait until that is finished. Do that part in the `subscribe` callback: `data => this.data = data.User.map(user => user.Name)`

Comment: Define "not working". Also, please add the new code you're using to your question. Both the part where you assign the value and where you try to read it

Comment: So you already take the `User` part in the `map(...)` part, no reason to do that again...  Should be: `data => this.data = data.map(user => user.Name)`